# dmidecode: Find accurate number of cores being used

Tags: cpu, core

I am trying to understand my dmidecode output. For simplicity let's say I am using **[this dmidecode output](https://github.com/rdobson/python-hwinfo/blob/master/hwinfo/host/tests/data/dmidecode)** as my reference. For both CPU1 and CPU2, dmidecode says there are 4 cores enabled and 8 threads. Does this mean there are a total of 8 cores or is it still 4 cores?

Some clarification on this would be very helpful

Comment: Can you post the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | /bin/egrep 'processor|model name|cache size|core|sibling|physical'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system has a single CPU with 4 cores and 8 threads, ie it has only 4 cores.

The [X3450](http://ark.intel.com/products/42929/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X3450-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz) processor you have is specified as 4 cores, 8 threads by Intel, so that fits.   Also, I'm pretty certain the Dell Poweredge [R310](http://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/poweredge-r310/pd) only supports a single CPU.

None of this explains why your DMIDECODE output shows 2 physical CPU's.  My guess is that is a reporting [bug](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/number-of-cpu-core-736405/) related to hyperthreading.